# VB.NET/IIS7/WinSrv 2008(無印)にて、開発環境のVBを毎度コンパイルさせたい

Tags: vb.net

現在開発環境にてVB.NET(.aspx)を作成しています。
しかし、書き換えても表示部分に変更が無ければコンパイル済みキャッシュが再利用されてしまい修正しても素直に反映されません。
そのため、コンパイルされて、この動作なのか、キャッシュが残っているから前回のどうさがそのままなのか判別できず、毎度表示部分に1を足したり消したりしています。
web.configを書き換えるなどで毎度際コンパイルする方法はないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

--【追記】状況【14:48】--
=IIS/VB.NET共に詳しくなくそもそもおかしなことをしている恐れもあります=
ドキュメントルート：C:\www\appname\
ファイル：def.aspx
(Studio関係ではなくSublimeTextなどのシンプルなエディタで修正)
表示方法 http://devsrvaddr/appname/ へアクセスする

```
<%
    Dim test as String = "ABC"
%>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>Hello.<%= test %></body>
</html>
```

ブラウザ => Hello.ABC

これを次のように編集して保存し、ブラウザでアクセス

```
<%
    Dim test as String = "XYZ"
%>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>Hello.<%= test %></body>
</html>
```

ブラウザ => Hello.ABC
と、何度リロードしても変化はありません。
<% - %>内を書き換えても再コンパイルせずキャッシュが利用されます
そこで、出力される部分を少し修正します。! を足すだけです。

```
<%
    Dim test as String = "XYZ"
%>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>!Hello.<%= test %></body>
</html>
```

ブラウザ !Hello.XYZ
と、出力部分を少し変更すると再コンパイルしてくれます。

Comment: デプロイ時に既存のファイルを消してもキャッシュが使用されるのでしょうか

Comment: 前回に続けて有難う御座います。キャッシュを見に行くと、16進数のファイル名になってしまっており特定ができず、引継ぎ時にテストだけど消しちゃいけないものもあると聞いており消すに消せません。すいません。

Answer (score 0):

サーバ上のASPXファイルを直接書き換えているのですよね？
通常サイト内のASPXファイルを書き換えればサーバ側のキャッシュは自動的に更新されるはずですが
サーバ側ではなくて、ブラウザのキャッシュが効いてる可能性はありませんか？

ASP.NETのキャッシュは色々なやり方で指定できるのですが、とりあえずIISマネージャーで該当サイトのキャッシュ設定を確認してみては

Comment: 有難う御座います。しかしながらサーバーキャッシュは何も設定されておらず（キャッシュするファイル一覧が空欄）、ブラウザキャッシュではなくサーバー側のキャッシュです。 *.aspxは%>この出力部分<%を書き換えれば<% REM 処理部分 %>も反映されるのですが、出力部分を変更せず、処理部分だけ書き換えても反映されないのです。

Comment: 軽く試した範囲では再現しませんね。Web.configファイルを削除して試しても同じ結果になりますか？